# What is oneAPI and how does it compare to TBB?

Tags: c++, tbb, intel-oneapi

We've been using TBB for years and I see when upgrading, we're taken to a oneAPI TBB page now instead. Does oneAPI TBB replace the traditional TBB? Are both versions being maintained or is the standalone TBB now deprecated?

Trying to determine which to migrate to. Looks to me like oneAPI TBB replaces TBB, as the TBB pages haven't been updated since last year but I can't easily tell.

What also confuses me is that in the include directory, there exists both tbb/tbb.h and oneapi/tbb/tbb.h and both have the same files within them. Are they identical? I can't tell which to use.

Comment: Helpful to provide a link to the page that you were taken to after upgrade.

Comment: Page? I just downloaded a new tarball

Comment: You're the one who called it a page. "we're taken to a oneAPI TBB page"  If that page is online, provide the link.  If it is in a downloaded tarball, provide the relative path inside the tarball.  Make it possible for someone else to see what you're seeing and asking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

oneTBB is the next version of TBB. While they are almost source compatible, the binary compatibility is not preserved and some interfaces were either removed or changed. Consider the topics: [Migrating from Threading Building Blocks (TBB)](https://docs.oneapi.io/versions/latest/onetbb/tbb_userguide/Migration_Guide.html) and [TBB Revamp](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/tbb-revamp.html).

As for `tbb.h`, all oneAPI components reside inside `oneapi/`, i.e. it is recommended to use `oneapi/tbb.h`(while `tbb/tbb.h` is the same and available for source compatibility with TBB)